# Small circle rolling without gliding on a large circle

Tags: geometry, circles

The following is now a celebrated problem whose solution appeared in the general media. However I believe that some of the answers given are wrong.

Take a "large" disk with radius 1 and a "small" disk with radius $1/N$ where $N\in \mathbb N^*$. The small disk is rolling without gliding on the large disk and the question is: how many complete revolutions the small disk should do to go back to the initial configuration?

Comment: Please don't be so *enigmatic*.

Comment: The answer is $N+1$. Which wrong solutions are you alluding to?

Comment: No doubt some of the answers given _are_ wrong. When a problem is popular, all kinds of people will publish their answers somewhere or other, and some of them will make mistakes. What answers have you seen? Which ones are wrong? Why do you think so? Which one is correct? Why do you think so?

Comment: As a matter of fact none of the solutions proposed for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149234/puzzle-a-coin-rolls-without-slipping-around-another-coin?rq=1) is really convincing. Were you thinking of them?

Comment: Here's another proposed solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kN3AOMrnEUs

Answer (score 2):

Let's see if I can give a satisfying geometrical answer, without invoking angular speed, frame changes, or hand-waving arguments.

Suppose the small circle has center $P$ when it starts, touching the large circle at $A$. After one full rotation of the small circle, its center will be at some point $P'$, while that point of the small circle which was touching the large circle at $A$ will be now at $A'$, with $A'P'$ parallel to $AP$.

But as one can see from the diagram below, after one full rotation the contact point is not at $A'$ but at some point $B$ and $x=\angle BP'A'=\angle AOB$. Only those points of the small circle forming arc $BA'$ (pink in the diagram) have been in contact with the large circle, hence the length of arc $BA'$ is the same as the length of arc $AB$ in the large circle, that is:
$$
(2\pi-x){1\over N}=x,
\quad\hbox{whence:}\quad
x={2\pi\over N+1}.
$$ 
After one rotation, then, the center of the small disk has covered a central angle $POP'=2\pi/(N+1)$: in order to complete a full $2\pi$ revolution around the large circle, $N+1$ rotations of the small disk are then needed.

[image]

Comment: It is indeed a mathematically convincing argument.